# How to read the value of this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

[image]

I came across this capacitor in a voltage converter which was converting 9V to 5V. This capacitor was connected at the output of M7805CT (i.e. between the 5V and common terminal) in parallel to another 470μF electrolytic capacitor. I cannot find a definite value of this capacitor. Different websites are providing different values of this coded capacitor. Here is the screenshot of what google search returned.[image]

Please help in decoding the value of this capacitor.

Comment: How about measuring the capacitance?

Comment: Distributors often use the same photo for capacitors of different value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

0.1uF (100nF) +/-5% tolerance (J),  100VDC rating.

It's a polyester (probably) film capacitor.

[Here](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_F3101_R82.pdf) is a similar type of capacitor (maybe the same type) from Kemet.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Spehro Pefhany already provided the correct answer. Also check the comments below this answer.

The capacitors you mention are NOT using the default capacitor code, which normally is 3 digits for the value followed by one character for the tolerance, and optionally prefixed by a multiplier.

In this link there is a table: [Capacitor-Codes](https://synthrotek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Capacitor-Codes.pdf)

And at the bottom is an additional description (which do not apply your capacitor).

[image]

Comment: This isn't too helpful for this particular capacitor though. This one is labelled differently to the table in your link. The capacitor in the question is 100nF, or 0.1µF. According to your link, this should have a code of 104 (which, to be fair, the majority of capacitors do!), so while this link is good for finding values on the majority of capacitors, it is not much use for this particular one (with the exception of tolerance).

Comment: it is partly useful how to read reputable sources that standardize codes and have their brand icon or name on their parts. These cheap parts have none of these quality indicators. does not deserve a down vote  @MCG These suppliers are so cheap they can't even afford a leading 0

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 my downvote was based on the fact that this answer does not correspond to this particular question. If it was an answer to a question about standardised capacitor codes, it would have certainly got an upvote. I cast my votes based on how well the answer actually answers the question being asked. However, I always leave a comment explaining my reasoning, and if it is fixed, my vote will usually change. I personally believe this is a good way of voting, I am not one to downvote and leave. I think most users would appreciate this, as I do for people who help me improve my answers

Comment: I appreciate those who improve answer more that criticize it

Comment: @MichelKeijzers there is no need to delete it. As I explained in my previous comment, I have given my reason for the downvote, which is not meant in a bad way. It is to give you my reasoning so that the answer can be edited and/or improved. I think my reasoning was quite appropriate

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I don't understand what you mean? The comment I left was to help improve the answer, otherwise I would have just downvoted it and left. I am hoping that comment was not directed at me as I wasn't being critical, otherwise my original comment would have said 'This is wrong' and left it there without explaining *why* I thought that

Comment: based on the quality of the laser printing, I would doubt these parts would have the very low ESR expected from PU metalized film caps required for SMPS outputs. I would even highly doubt they are 5% parts. Michel shows the proper way parts should be labelled and this mfg does not meet any standards of labelling. SO I would never choose them.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: out of curiosity - how did you know MCG downvoted? Is this an information available at a certain rep level?

Comment: Nyet just intuition

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 your comment is completely irrelevant. Yes, this answer shows the way parts *should* be labelled. I am not disputing that. My comment was a response to the fact that this particular answer was not relevant *to the question asked*. Just because you don't like the labeling and would not choose the part does **not** mean the answer should be treated as correct. I think you are overreacting to what was literally a simple comment on how the answer could be improved. By the edit on the answer, Michel has taken the comments into consideration.......

Comment: ..... instead of arguing, which shows he understood the points made, and as such, his answer is now relative to the original question. This also proves that my comment was useful. Also, @WoJ I did cast a down vote on this answer, along with a reason explaining why. Now the point I made was addressed and the answer edited, I have removed my down vote. That is what the voting and commenting is for. To improve the quality of the answers and to keep them relevant to the question (although sunnyskyguy apparently thinks the question is irrelevant to the answer for some reason!)

Comment: @MCG: I understand. I was curious about the mechanics of the site, not arguing with any of the comments or answers.

Comment: @MCG I dont think that at all. My point was it is partly useful. I just dont appreciate downvotes that have merit but could be improved. I also I appreciate those who improve answer more that criticize it. Just my opinion that you could have suggested an improvement without the negative judgement, practiced all too frequently by others, which you did after I suggested it had value.